# Meteor - Facebook authorization simply isn't working

Tags: facebook, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm running a meteor app from a server at `http://example.com:3000` and trying to get it to authorize via Facebook using `accounts-facebook`.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<head>
  <title>appname</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  {{>loginButtons}}

  {{#if currentUser}}
    Logged in
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

I do have `accounts-ui` and `accounts-facebook` enabled. I went through the Facebook app registration process. Here are my basic settings:

[image: Basic Settings]

My advanced settings are default, and I have switched the "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" on in Status & Review.

When I actually try to log on using Facebook, the authorization window redirects to `http://localhost:3000/_oauth/facebook?code=AQBaOoQ8XVQvzdqH8dyF03vVVP3daO9UO-tB0IZYCsYOYxL0LFWVrZUt2Rh34I2HI8Y5kofDP8sj46dn--N1pk6h0WOfoLAoaZxJzwSjocmBrRowjGv8JWcyN42msFuUdQAxQzbyrhnE2mQFUQISBOVzbnsR20ozS1pUmSdCb9BbmbidS8NvKvtEmSXm1lh9zPH7DYG4KfWQ2yIWSO8JMLEWa04TOP5rLDc75ak4WfXr1emb25T7981HUL8pCF_d_NgbFCNojoyY2yIB80e1nHxhovr-V3UWcCrNjH8aljTxy-qVGCmuLa4GravNIRfy9I8&state=eyJsb2dpblN0eWxlIjoicG9wdXAiLCJjcmVkZW50aWFsVG9rZW4iOiJlUkpSQjRja0FqVmJTWklCajhvQ01IdGlVdkktNnBXcF81d0RGR3Rod1lDIn0%3D#_=_`, which isn't a valid address as the server is run and accessed remotely.

Additionally (and I suppose most problematically), the page doesn't acknowledge that any authorization has occurred, and acts like the login has failed (so I assume it has).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has to do with the fact that facebook believes the app is hosted at localhost, but if I change the Valid OAuth redirect URIs to be example.com, the authorization still tries to go to the localhost address, but fails because that address isn't whitelisted.

Comment: Can you run console.log(process.env.ROOT_URL) somewhere in your server side code and see what your ROOT_URL is?

Comment: @WillParker `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: @WillParker Thanks! Now I understand what the ROOT_URL does. I just had to change it to example.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make Meteor try to redirect from the Facebook login to the correct landing page (hosted at `example.com`, not `localhost`), I needed to make Meteor acknowledge that it's being run on `example.com`, not `localhost:3000`. The way to do this was to set the environment variable `ROOT_URL`.

On bash:

```
export ROOT_URL=http://example.com:3000
```

If you're running the site on example.com on port 3000, be sure to put it in your `.profile` or equivalent to make the environment variable persist between sessions.

Answer (score 3):

Check the redirect URI on the "Advanced" tab.

It should be like this:`http://localhost:3000/_oauth/facebook`

NOT like this: `http://localhost:3000/_oauth/facebook?close`

Answer (score 2):

Lets try this.

First go through

**My apps > Test apps**

[image: example fB developers]
Now on the top-right there is a Green button `create a test app`

[image: Green button facebook]

Now some kind of modal appears, `Test App Name` and `Test App Namespace`, select whatever name you want

**First**

on **Basic** complete this 2 options

Now on App Domains select

```
localhost:3000
```

and on the site URL.

```
localhost:3000
```

and on **advanced**, on the Valid OAuth redirect URIs

```
http://localhost:3000/sessions/create
```

**Second**

on the `/server/facebook-config.js for example`, add this code.

```
    // first, remove configuration entry in case service is already configured
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
  service: "facebook"
});
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
  service: "facebook",
  appId: "yourTestAppId",
  secret: "yourTesSecret"
});
```

And it should work

Comment: When I try to add localhost:3000 to App Domains, it says Top-Level Domains aren't allowed. If I don't put the App Domain in (the site URL is localhost:3000), I get `Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.` when I try to log in.

Comment: but you change the Secret  and App id, from the `test app`?

Comment: Yes. I was able to change the App Domains to be `http://localhost:3000` instead of `localhost:3000`, but that didn't change anything either.

Answer (score 1):

@RiverTam's answer did it for me! I have self-signed SSL cert on localhost with `SSLProxy` and I was under the wrong assumption that you could add custom routes to the callback URL, so I had to do several things:

#### 1. In the meteor run command, export ROOT_URL first before meteor run

```
export ROOT_URL=https://localhost:3100; meteor --settings settings-development.json --port 3100
```

#### 2. Add the callback url that FB wants, with localhost domain

Navigate to `FB App in developer.facebook.com => Facebook Login => Settings => Client OAuth Settings` and add URL like so:

[image]

#### 3. Leave Domain empty

This is under `FB App in developer.facebook.com => Settings => Advanced => Domain Manager`

*+999999 to River Tam for FireFly reference :P*